Aligning non-symmetric image in equation
I have the following line of code which was in pure tikz code, but due to issues with LuaLaTex and submitting papers, I had to do it this way:
\begin{equation}
\vcenter{\hbox{$i\mathcal{M}_2$}} \quad=\quad \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{1loopshoestring.png}}}
\label{shoestring total feynman diagram}
\end{equation}

where the image is: 
Now, I really do not like doing it this way, but for the moment his is the only way. My problem is though that I want to align the LHS of the equation with the wavy-line (it is a graviton) but with my current code, I cannot figure out how to do it. Really, I just want to lower the RHS with the image but a certain amount to align it, but I do not know how to do that.
Thanks for any suggestions, and let me know if you need any of my preamble code or anything. I have graphicx loaded in the normal way.

use
\begin{equation}
i\mathcal{M}_2
=
\raisebox{-5pt}{\includegraphics{abc}}
\end{equation}

and adjust the -5pt to whatever looks right for your actual image.

That was unbelievably simple, thank you.
